# Angularjs $http.get is not working in Firefox new version

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Angularjs $http.get is not triggering when using Firefox v50 & above.

From the below Angularjs function, always returning "result is 2" and sysout is not printing at all that mean Spring controller method is not being called up every time . No error at browser console as well as server side. Is there any solution for this?

When i hit the url www.xxxx.com/api/checkSession it displays 2 in browser but its not triggering CheckSession Spring method.

I have resolved by problem using POST. Please check my answer below.

CheckSession.js

```
this.checkSession = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/checkSession').then(function(response) {
        result = parseInt(response.data);
        if(result==2){
            jAlert("Your Session is Expired!",null,function(){ 
            });
        } else{
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

SessionController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkSession", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody int checkSession(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    int status = 0;
    if (httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("email") != null) {
        status = 1;
    } else {
         System.out.println("Email"+httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("email"));
        status = 2;
        if (httpRequest.getSession() != null)
            httpRequest.getSession().invalidate();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: add console.log() to your javascript to see if youre even getting in the function.

Comment: @Stephan When i debug through browser it shows 2 & When i hit the url www.xxxx.com/api/checkSession it displays 2 in browser.

Comment: What is the value of the session attribute when the method is called? Presumably it's null.

Comment: I think its null so only it executes else block and returns 2. but sysout is not printed and all other sysout is printing

Comment: Are you getting your alert? Also, when you put a break point and step through the server side code, do you enter the function? If either case is correct, then your function IS being called and your question is not stating the real problem.

Comment: I got Your Session is Expired! alert everytime. i cannot debug through code. Its production site. Its occurs only in production

Comment: Ok then your question doesnt properly explain the problem. The way its written suggests the method is not being called at all, which is not the case. If it wasnt being called youd get a 500 error or some other value. The only way for you to get a response that contains a 2 on the body to trigger the alert is for the method to return successfully. I suggest you spend some time more clearly defining the issue you are trying to solve, and either edit this question to reflect the actual problem, or close this question and make a new one.

Comment: @ Stephen. Please see my answer below. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have resolved the problem by using **POST method instead of GET method** both in AngularJS & Spring controller method. Now Spring method being called up every time.

But i don't know why $http.get method is not calling Spring controller method and getting result is 2 always in AngularJS mehood. Kindly answer if anybody knows it. Thanks.

Comment: 'is not calling Spring controller method' this is incorrect. It IS calling the method, or you would not be getting a response to parse into a 2...

Comment: Stephen, sysout is not printing inside that method but when i use chrome its printing. I don't know where i got 2 may be from cache.

Comment: turn the cache off in chrome dev tools, and retry. if you still get a 2, it's not the cache, and probably an issue with the logger configurations

Comment: Stephen, i wonder its working in chrome, but not working in latest firefox browsers because not even calling the method from Spring controller. I have used sysout to check whether the method is being called or not in prodcution. When is use chrome browser the sysout is printing and when i use latest firefox version sysout is not printing. Now i have changed to POST method, now everything is working fine.